# ANYCHART LinearColorScale

Tags: java, android, java-me, anychart

I'm trying to construct a linearColorScale of AnyChart, and I've tried the code below but haven't gotten any results. Please let me know if there is a bug in this code or if I am missing something.

P.S. As said, I modified minSDK 19 and followed the documentation. Please let me know if there is anything I'm missing:)

TIA.

```
   public class GeneralFragment extends Fragment {

    AnyChartView daysScale;
    private View view;
    private LineChart symbolDetailChart;
    private ArrayList<Entry> values;
    private LineDataSet set1;
    private LineData data;
    private Drawable drawablePositive = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Logs.globalContext, R.drawable.graph_green_bg);



    public GeneralFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general, container, false);

        daysScale = view.findViewById(R.id.scalechartdays);
       
        LinearGauge linearGauge = AnyChart.linear();

        linearGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new Double[] { 5.3D }));

        linearGauge.layout(Layout.HORIZONTAL);

        linearGauge.label(0)
                .position(Position.LEFT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("-50px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("black")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(0).text("Total Rainfall");

        linearGauge.label(1)
                .position(Position.LEFT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("40px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("#777777")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(1).text("Drought Hazard");

        linearGauge.label(2)
                .position(Position.RIGHT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("40px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("#777777")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(2).text("Flood Hazard");

        OrdinalColor scaleBarColorScale = OrdinalColor.instantiate();
        scaleBarColorScale.ranges(new String[]{
                "{ from: 0, to: 2, color: ['red 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 2, to: 3, color: ['yellow 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 3, to: 7, color: ['green 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 7, to: 8, color: ['yellow 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 8, to: 10, color: ['red 0.5'] }"
        });

        linearGauge.scaleBar(0)
                .width("5%")
                .colorScale(scaleBarColorScale);

        linearGauge.marker(0)
                .type(MarkerType.TRIANGLE_DOWN)
                .color("red")
                .offset("-3.5%")
                .zIndex(10);

        linearGauge.scale()
                .minimum(0)
                .maximum(10);
//        linearGauge.scale().ticks

        linearGauge.axis(0)
                .minorTicks(false)
                .width("1%");
        linearGauge.axis(0)
                .offset("-1.5%")
                .orientation(Orientation.TOP)
                .labels("top");

        linearGauge.padding(0, 30, 0, 30);

        daysScale.setChart(linearGauge);

       

        return  view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart configuration code is absolutely ok. Below is the working code and the resulting chart. You should check errors and debug the rest of your code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);

        LinearGauge linearGauge = AnyChart.linear();

        linearGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new Double[] { 5.3D }));

        linearGauge.layout(Layout.HORIZONTAL);

        linearGauge.label(0)
                .position(Position.LEFT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("-50px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("black")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(0).text("Total Rainfall");

        linearGauge.label(1)
                .position(Position.LEFT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("40px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("#777777")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(1).text("Drought Hazard");

        linearGauge.label(2)
                .position(Position.RIGHT_CENTER)
                .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
                .offsetY("40px")
                .offsetX("50px")
                .fontColor("#777777")
                .fontSize(17);
        linearGauge.label(2).text("Flood Hazard");

        OrdinalColor scaleBarColorScale = OrdinalColor.instantiate();
        scaleBarColorScale.ranges(new String[]{
                "{ from: 0, to: 2, color: ['red 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 2, to: 3, color: ['yellow 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 3, to: 7, color: ['green 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 7, to: 8, color: ['yellow 0.5'] }",
                "{ from: 8, to: 10, color: ['red 0.5'] }"
        });

        linearGauge.scaleBar(0)
                .width("5%")
                .colorScale(scaleBarColorScale);

        linearGauge.marker(0)
                .type(MarkerType.TRIANGLE_DOWN)
                .color("red")
                .offset("-3.5%")
                .zIndex(10);

        linearGauge.scale()
                .minimum(0)
                .maximum(10);
//        linearGauge.scale().ticks

        linearGauge.axis(0)
                .minorTicks(false)
                .width("1%");
        linearGauge.axis(0)
                .offset("-1.5%")
                .orientation(Orientation.TOP)
                .labels("top");

        linearGauge.padding(0, 30, 0, 30);

        anyChartView.setChart(linearGauge);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: it's working fine in activity but not in fragment. the code and screenshot your have attached is of activity and I am working inside the fragment.

Comment: The Fragment is not supported in the current version of the library.